# Finitely presented subgroup of finitely presented group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

If I am given a group $G$, which is finitely presented by $\langle S \mid R \rangle$, and I am given a finitely presented subgroup $H$ of $G$. Is it true that $H$ takes the form $\langle T \mid R' \rangle$ for $T \subset S$ and $R' \subset R$?

Comment: As another example:  The commutator subgroup of the free group on two letters is infinitely generated, hence it contains the free group on $n$ letters for any $n$.

Comment: Already deleted my comment, your example seems better. Thanks!

Comment: @lulu If you have an answer, please post it as an answer, not as a comment. [See this for the rationale.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/23417/10014)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is not even true if $G$ is finite. Take the cyclic group $G:=\langle x \mid x^4=1 \rangle$, then $H:=\{ 1, x^2 \}$ is a finite subgroup (so clearly finitely presentable), but its only generating set is not s subset of the generators of $G$.